Create a flowchart in latex

How to create a flowchart like this in latex? So far I have not been able to achieve anything close to this. My code is as follows.
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto,
      level1/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, rounded corners, text width=4em, text centered, minimum height=2em},
      level2/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, rounded corners, text width=4em, text centered, minimum height=2em},
      level3/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, rounded corners, text width=4em, text centered, minimum height=2em}]
    
      % Root node
      \node [level1] (root) {Root};
    
      % Level 2 nodes
      \node [level2, right of=root] (node1) {Node 1};
      \node [level2, right of=node1] (node2) {Node 2};
      \node [level2, right of=node2] (node3) {Node 3};
      \node [level2, right of=node3] (node4) {Node 4};
      \node [level2, right of=node4] (node5) {Node 5};
    
      % Level 3 nodes
      \node [level3, below of=node1, yshift=-1cm] (child1) {Child 1};
      \node [level3, below of=node2, yshift=-1cm] (child2) {Child 2};
      \node [level3, below of=node3, yshift=-1cm] (child3) {Child 3};
      \node [level3, below of=node4, yshift=-1cm] (child4) {Child 4};
      \node [level3, below of=node5, yshift=-1cm] (child5) {Child 5};
    
      % Arrows
      \foreach \from in {root}
        \foreach \to in {node1, node2, node3, node4, node5}
          \draw [->] (\from) -- (\to);
      \foreach \from in {node1, node2, node3, node4, node5}
        \foreach \to in {child1, child2, child3}
          \draw [->] (\from) -- (\to);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}



Welcome. // Can you please add a screenshot of yozr codes result? Thank you. // Many people will suggest using forest.

Here is a forest solution.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={
    grow'=0,
    align=center,
    minimum width=3cm,
    anchor=center,
    inner xsep=3mm,
    rounded corners,
    font=\small,
    if level=1{fill=orange, text=white}
        {if level=2{fill=brown, text=white}{draw=red}}
}
[Root node, rotate=90, fill=red, text=white
    [level 1 node
        [level 2 node
            [Some very long reference]
        ]
        [level 2 node
            [Some very long reference\\with two lines]
        ]
    ]
    [level 1 node
        [level 2 node
            [Another even longer reference\\with two lines]
        ]
        [level 2 node
            [Some very long reference\\with two lines]
        ]
        [level 2 node\\has two lines
            [Some reference[Another reference]]
            [Some reference\\with two lines[Another reference\\with two lines]]
        ]
    ]
    [level 1 node
        [level 2 node
            [A very very very long long long reference\\with two lines]
        ]
        [level 2 node
            [A very very very long long long reference]
        ]
    ]
    [level 1 node
        [level 2 node
            [A very very very long long long reference]
        ]
        [level 2 node
            [A long reference]
        ]
    ]
    [level 1 node
        [level 2 node
            [A very very very long long long reference]
        ]
        [level 2 node
            [A very very very long long long reference]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}


+1 Nice and compact.

There are many ways to do it, e.g. using the child-approach from the pgfmanual, using package forest, using a matrix to place nodes, using tiklzlibrary positioning etc.
When you are a beginner I suggest to do it more object-by-object, with a high degree of control. So the following basically:

put the nodes in a reasonable way
draws required connections

I documented the relevant steps in the comments, with focus on the intersting part in the middle. I suggest to try repeating these from scratch for training reasons, and to see, how code evolves from simple to refined. I suggest to look up these commands in parallel in the pgfmanual.
The first code shows the result, once you're done with placement and connections. The second is a bout beautifying, i.e. introducing color etc.
Several parameters are there for adjustments. Besides the branches they all are localized in the style section. So changes there go almost allways right. The one for the branches could and should be moved into a \newcommand for further refactoring.
Getting nodes and connections done
Starting backwards, work from rightmost children to root.
Rotating the roots node is tricky, so I left it as is for now.
For the connections there are two things:

an outcommented trials, to check for good code, and refactoring into a loop, using pairs of nodes (well, their names)
same for the branches, with introducing one intermediate point as relative coordinate


% ~~~ makes development much easier ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

% ~~~ PROCESS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%       care for positioning text, first
% 1)    start with node at (0,0), ignoring all colors etc.
% 2)    put next node above it, introduce style up
% 3)    continue, introduce style and nodes for dn
% 4)    introduce brown child level as nodes + style lft
% 4b)   making nodes width the same, i.e. adjust style lft
% 5)    introducing orange children, style lftb reuses lft
% 6)    introducing ROOT and extra
% 7)    adding simple and branched connections


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% ~~~ introducing styles as suitable
        up/.style={draw,anchor=south west,yshift=2mm},
        dn/.style={draw,anchor=north west,yshift=-2mm},
        lft/.style={draw,anchor=east,xshift=-4mm,minimum width=2cm},
        lftb/.style={lft,minimum width=32mm,yshift=-4mm},
        rt/.style={draw,anchor=west,xshift=4mm},
        root/.style={draw,xshift=-10mm,yshift=-9mm,
                     rotate=0,anchor=east},
    ]
 
    % ~~~ starting backwards with "rightmost" child level ~~~
    % ~~~ upwards
    \node[draw] (D0) at (0,0)           {Denoisung};
    \node[up]   (D1) at (D0.north west) {HDR};
    \node[up]   (D2) at (D1.north west) {Semantic NeRF};

    % ~~~ downwards
    \node[dn]   (D-1) at (D0.south west) {GIRAFFE};
    \node[dn]   (D-2) at (D-1.south west){Dream Fusion};
    
    % ~~~ brown children ~~~~~
    \node[lft]  (C-1) at (D-2.west)      {Diffusion};
    \node[lft]  (C1)  at (D1.west)       {Semantics};
    \node[lft]  (C2)  at (D2.west)       {Editing};
    % ~~~ this one is special ~~~~~~~~~
    \node[lft,yshift=-4mm] (C0)  at (D0.west) {Functional};
    
    % ~~~ orange children ~~~~~~~~~~    
    \node[lftb] (B0) at (C0.west)        {Generative Models};
    \node[lftb] (B1) at (C2.west)        {Image Processing};
    
    % ~~~ ROOT ~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[root] (RT) at (B1.west) {Applications};
    
    % ~~~ extra ~~~~~~~~~
    \node[rt] (X0) at (D0.east) {RawNeRF};
    
    % ~~~ SIMPLE connections ~~~~~~~~~
%   \draw (C2) -- (D2); 
%   \draw (C1) -- (D1); 
%   now refactored, i.e. as loop
    \foreach \a/\b in {C2/D2, C1/D1, D0/X0, C-1/D-2}
        \draw (\a) -- (\b);
    
    % ~~~ branched connections ~~~~~~~~
%   \draw (C0.east) -- +(.2,0) |-  (D0.west);
%   \draw (C0.east) -- +(.2,0) |-  (D-1.west);
%   now refactored, i.e. as loop
    \foreach \a/\b in  {C0/D0, C0/D-1,
                        B1/C2, B1/C1, B0/C0, B0/C-1,
                        RT/B1, RT/B0}
        \draw (\a.east) -- +(.2,0) |- (\b.west);    
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Beautifying
This is almost boring now:

define styles for the various levels
add said styles to the relevant nodes

It may be a good idea to actually delete the trials, when you add more to the diagram. For doing so, just follow the patterns:

new node, now with correct style combinations, and new node names
adding required connections to both \draw-loops
make small steps in doing so, to recognize and fix trouble early

I suggest to rethink, IF it's a good idea to introduce multi-line text. Though it's possible, chances are you have to re-adjust several styles, perhaps even change some approaches. Usually: less is more - more ore less ...

% ~~~ makes development much easier ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

% ~~~ PROCESS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%       now let's take care of colors and shapes
% 8)    define styles nd etc. AND add to the relevant nodes


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% ~~~ introducing styles as suitable
        up/.style={draw,anchor=south west,yshift=2mm},
        dn/.style={draw,anchor=north west,yshift=-2mm},
        lft/.style={draw,anchor=east,xshift=-4mm,
                    minimum width=2cm},
        lftb/.style={lft,minimum width=32mm,yshift=-4mm},
        rt/.style={draw,anchor=west,xshift=4mm},
        root/.style={draw,xshift=-10mm,yshift=-9mm,
                     rotate=0,anchor=east},
        % ~~~ now the colors etc. ~~~~~~~~~~
        nd/.style={draw=red,rounded corners},
        nc/.style={draw=none,rounded corners,fill=brown!30},
        nb/.style={draw=none,rounded corners,fill=orange!30},
        nr/.style={draw=none,rounded corners,fill=red,
                   text=white,},% not recommended !
    ]
 
    % ~~~ starting backwards with "rightmost" child level ~~~
    % ~~~ upwards
    \node[draw,nd] (D0) at (0,0)           {Denoisung};
    \node[up,nd]   (D1) at (D0.north west) {HDR};
    \node[up,nd]   (D2) at (D1.north west) {Semantic NeRF};

    % ~~~ downwards
    \node[dn,nd]   (D-1) at (D0.south west) {GIRAFFE};
    \node[dn,nd]   (D-2) at (D-1.south west){Dream Fusion};
    
    % ~~~ brown children ~~~~~
    \node[lft,nc]  (C-1) at (D-2.west)      {Diffusion};
    \node[lft,nc]  (C1)  at (D1.west)       {Semantics};
    \node[lft,nc]  (C2)  at (D2.west)       {Editing};
    % ~~~ this one is special ~~~~~~~~~
    \node[lft,yshift=-4mm,nc] (C0)  at (D0.west) {Functional};
    
    % ~~~ orange children ~~~~~~~~~~    
    \node[lftb,nb] (B0) at (C0.west)         {Generative Models};
    \node[lftb,nb] (B1) at (C2.west)         {Image Processing};
    
    % ~~~ ROOT ~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[root,nr] (RT) at (B1.west) {Applications};
    
    % ~~~ extra ~~~~~~~~~
    \node[rt,nd] (X0) at (D0.east) {RawNeRF};
    
    % ~~~ SIMPLE connections ~~~~~~~~~
%   \draw (C2) -- (D2); 
%   \draw (C1) -- (D1); 
%   now refactored, i.e. as loop
    \foreach \a/\b in {C2/D2, C1/D1, D0/X0, C-1/D-2}
        \draw (\a) -- (\b);
    
    % ~~~ branched connections ~~~~~~~~
%   \draw (C0.east) -- +(.2,0) |-  (D0.west);
%   \draw (C0.east) -- +(.2,0) |-  (D-1.west);
%   now refactored, i.e. as loop
    \foreach \a/\b in  {C0/D0, C0/D-1,
                        B1/C2, B1/C1, B0/C0, B0/C-1,
                        RT/B1, RT/B0}
        \draw (\a.east) -- +(.2,0) |- (\b.west);    
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

